# Cannot find jdeps command (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, jdeps

I'm using Java 8 update 45 on my mac.
I've tried to use 'jdeps' command, but my mac keeps showing "command not found" message. Weird thing is that other command in the bin folder like 'java', 'javac' perfectly works. Only 'jdeps' command is not working.

How can I use jdeps command? Is there any condition to use this command?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely there in the version I have on Mac:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

The crux the it seems to be that some of the things in the above don't get the magic mentioned below:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2015/Nov/msg00009.html

> ```
> When the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set Mac OS X does some magic
>
> But the problem is not all the commands are covered, and some are missing from newer JDKs
> ```

The links don't appear in:

```
$ ls -l `which java`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74  1 Jul  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk_version/Contents/Home
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```