MuleSoft Java Custom Connector Build Error jdeps command
I'm trying to build mulesoft json logger supported with JAVA 17 version and when am trying to publish to exchange am getting below error
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jdeps-plugin:3.1.2:jdkinternals (default) on project json-logger: Unable to find jdeps command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set

I'm on my mac machine
/usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home

which java
/usr/bin/java

any idea what am missing here..
Here is the pom.xml (I got this project from MuleSoft support Team). All the changes that were done is updating the pom and deleting AMQP , Broker Destinations
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>json-logger</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<packaging>mule-extension</packaging>
<name>JSON Logger - Mule 4.6+</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</parent>

<description>Mule modules that augment the core Mule functionality through the Mule Extension API</description>
<properties>
    <mtf.javaopts/>
    <mule.sdk.api.version>0.7.0</mule.sdk.api.version>
    <jackson.databind.version>2.10.3</jackson.databind.version>
    <common.lang.version>2.6</common.lang.version>
    <common.beanutils.version>1.9.4</common.beanutils.version>
    <joda.time.version>2.10.5</joda.time.version>
    <lmax.disruptor.version>3.4.2</lmax.disruptor.version>
    <json.path.version>2.4.0</json.path.version>
    <min.mule.version>4.6.0</min.mule.version>
    <munit.version>3.1.0</munit.version>
    <munit.extensions.maven.plugin.version>1.2.0</munit.extensions.maven.plugin.version>
    <mule.extensions.maven.plugin.version>1.6.0-rc1</mule.extensions.maven.plugin.version>

</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jdkinternals</goal>
                        <goal>test-jdkinternals</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.35</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.github.mulesoft-consulting</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-mule-annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <customAnnotator>org.mule.custom.annotation.utils.CustomMuleAnnotator</customAnnotator>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <targetPackage>org.mule.extension.jsonlogger.api.pojos</targetPackage>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <runtimeConfiguration>
                    <discoverRuntimes>
                        <minMuleVersion>${min.mule.version}</minMuleVersion>
                        <includeSnapshots>false</includeSnapshots>
                        <product>EE</product>
                    </discoverRuntimes>
                </runtimeConfiguration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Target Anypoint Organization Repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>Exchange2</id>
        <name>Exchange2 Repository</name>
        <!-- Update to US Based if your customer is in the US Control Plane -->
        <url>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/organizations/${project.groupId}/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sdk-api</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.sdk.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${common.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>${common.beanutils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>${json.path.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>${lmax.disruptor.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-extensions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${munit.extensions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Exchange2</id>
        <name>Exchange2 Repository</name>
        <!-- Update if on US Control Plane -->
        <url>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/organizations/${project.groupId}/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange V3</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>


Share the pom and what changes did you do to the project? Are you sure the sources are compatible with Java 17?

updated the question with pom.. changes were mostly deleting the destinations and reference to it.. (I got this from mulesoft support team) and they are not fully supporting it as this is a custom connector

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964142/cannot-find-jdeps-command-mac

yeah , I did see the article and not sure how to do symlink.. let me check on that..  (my system it just says /usr/bin/java , not showing up the link i guess)

when i enabled debug , I see this error  "mule-jar-handling-utils-4.6.0.jar is a multi-release jar file but --multi-release option is not set"

I did set multiRelease 17 in pom.xml and now am getting different error
"Execution default-extension-model of goal org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.6.0-rc1:extension-model failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.6.0-rc1:extension-model: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.aether.repository.RemoteRepository$Builder org.eclipse.aether.repository.RemoteRepository$Builder.setBlocked(boolean)"

I would not recommend to change undocumented settings.

I had a similar problem building a custom connector on Mac with maven. I installed temurin-8 and I manually set the JAVA_HOME environment variable before running maven.
➜ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home

I set it manually like so:
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version

Also I had to manually create a symbolic link in $JAVA_HOME/jre to $JAVA_HOME/bin/jdeps like so:
sudo ln -s $JAVA_HOME/bin/jdeps $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/

